# Wait for completion of ClosedShape stream

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have runnable graph of following form.

```
def getGraph[T](sequence: Seq[T], tickConsumers: Map[T, ActorRef]) =
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
    GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      val ticker = builder.add(new SomeTickProducer))
      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[T](sequence.length))
      ticker ~> broadcast
      sequence.foreach { item =>
        broadcast ~>
        builder.add(new SomeTickProcesser(item)) ~>
        Sink.actorRef(tickConsumers(item), NotUsed)
      }
      ClosedShape
    }
  )
```

So my graph is closed and doesn't produce any data, there is nothing I can materialize. Actually it just receives some data from outer service, processes them and broadcast to several consumers.

As far as `SomeTickProducer` creates quite significant load for outer service I should run not more that one such graph a time. Is there any way to convert my graph to something `Future`-like and wait for it's ending using `Await`? Or maybe there is some better way to organize some queue here?

Comment: Call `.run()` to materialize

Comment: Yep, that was first thing I've tried to do. `.run()` returns `Unit` and do not block actor.

Answer (score 3):

To get the graph to materialize a future, you need to give the `GraphDSL.create` method a stage that does so, like `Sink.ignore`. Then, you will be to access that stage from inside the `GraphDSL` builder.

Assuming that `SomeTickProducer` is a `Source` that will complete eventually, you can watch for the termination of of `SomeTickProducer` and forward that to the graph's outlet.

Then, when you materialize the graph, it will be of type `Future[Done]`.

This would work something like:

```
def getGraph[T](sequence: Seq[T], tickConsumers: Map[T, ActorRef]) =
  RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
    GraphDSL.create(Sink.ignore) { implicit builder => out =>
      val producer = new SomeTickProducer
      val ticker = builder.add(producer)
      val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[T](sequence.length))
      ticker ~> broadcast
      sequence.foreach { item =>
        broadcast ~>
        builder.add(new SomeTickProcesser(item)) ~>
        Sink.actorRef(tickConsumers(item), NotUsed)
      }
      producer.watchTermination()(Keep.none) ~> out
      ClosedShape
    }
  )
```

Comment: I tried this technique, looks like it doesn't work. Based on the doc for `waitTermination`: 'The `Future` completes with success when received complete message from upstream or cancel from downstream.' I have a `Source` that sends HTTP requests to a downstream `Flow` and the graph ends before it handles the HTTP responses when the `Source` finishes and I terminate the actor system.